# Android: NullPointerExceptions when recall function with Thread

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with this.
I'm using canvas to draw character.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.mcanvas = canvas;
    mcanvas.drawBitmap(mBg, null, mRect, mPaint);

    for (int i = temps.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        temps.get(i).onDraw(mcanvas);
    }
    for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);
    }
    while(timeleft>0) { 
        timeleft=(int) (timeleft-1);    
        score.onDraw(canvas,timeleft); break; 
    }
}
```

when i set drawBitmap for this function and Thread class run this.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;
    while (running) {
        Canvas c = null;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                view.onDraw(c);
            }

        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
        sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        try {
            if (sleepTime > 0)
                sleep(sleepTime);
            else
                sleep(2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

}
```

But when I replay game, logcat show error and close app.

```
06-13 02:04:12.347: E/AndroidRuntime(956): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-94
06-13 02:04:12.347: E/AndroidRuntime(956): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 02:04:12.347: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at com.example.Boss.GameView.onDraw(GameView.java:353)
06-13 02:04:12.347: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at com.example.Boss.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:30)
```

it shows an error in:

```
mcanvas.drawBitmap(mBg, null, mRect, mPaint);
```

and

```
view.onDraw(c);
```

I don't know what happened with it. i need help. Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
    sprite.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

try using for-loop instead, I used to have crash when running foreach loops 2 or more times in game, also post more details:

```
 for(int i =0; i< sprites.size(); i++){
      Sprite s = sprites.get(i);
      s.onDraw(canvas);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be that `mcanvas` is `null`. This can happen when `lockCanvas()` returns `null`. Please check the documentation of [`SurfcaeHolder.lockCanvas()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29) which says:

> A null is returned if the surface has not been created or otherwise cannot be edited. You will usually need to implement Callback.surfaceCreated to find out when the Surface is available for use.